# Is there a way to change directory in the terminal to a directory at a certain "index"?

Tags: linux, terminal, command

Let's say all the directories I want to change into have long names, so typing `cd "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit"` in the terminal each time is a hassle, but I've called `ls` and know that directory is, say, the first directory. Is there a way to change into it with something like `cd 0`? I.e. Can I change into whatever directory is at index X when sorted in the same manner as the results when calling `ls`?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such functionality. You can either use tab completion: `cd Lor<tab>` or write a function that does what you describe:

```
cdn() { 
  local n=$1
  for d in */
  do
    (( n-- )) || { cd "$d"; break; }
  done

  # Error checking left as an exercise
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@that other guy's answer is probably the best answer, but you could also use a script like this one:

```
#!/bin/sh

i=0
for directory in */ .*/
do
    i=$(($i+1))
    if [ $1 -eq $i ]
    then
        cd $directory
        break
    fi
done
```

The script iterates through all directories (including hidden directories and `./` and `../`), and stops when it reaches the index that you have chosen to `cd` into. There is one caveat to this however (and this is why @that other guy's answer is probably better): the script must be run with the `.` or `source` command (Ex: `. cd-index.sh 3` rather than `./cd-index.sh 3`). If you do not run it with `.` it will only change directories within the script.